# Using cassandra python driver with twisted

Tags: python-3.x, cassandra, twisted, autobahn, datastax-python-driver

My python application uses twisted, and uses cassandra python driver under the hood. Cassandra python driver can use `cassandra.io.twistedreactor.TwistedConnection` as a connection class to use twisted as a way to query.

`TwistedConnection` class uses timer and `reactor.callLater` to check if a query task has timed out.

The problem is when I use cassandra ORM (`cassandra.cqlengine.models.Model`) to query.

```
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns
from cassandra.cqlengine.models import Model


# ORM for user settings
class UserSettings(Model):
    userid = columns.Text(primary_key=True)
    settings = columns.Text()

# Function registered with autobahn/wamp
def worker():
    userid = "96c5d462-cf7c-11e7-b567-b8e8563d0920"

    def _query():
        # This is a blocking call, internally calling twisted reactor
        # to collect the query result
        setting = model.UserSettings.objects(userid=userid).get()
        return json.loads(setting.settings)

    threads.deferToThread(_query)
```

When run in `twisted.trial` unit tests. The test that uses above code always fails with

> Failure: twisted.trial.util.DirtyReactorAggregateError: Reactor was
>   unclean.
>
> ```
> DelayedCalls: (set twisted.internet.base.DelayedCall.debug = True to debug)
> <DelayedCall 0x10e0a2dd8 [9.98250699043274s] called=0 cancelled=0 TwistedLoop._on_loop_timer()
> ```

In the autobahn worker where this code used, however works fine.

The cassandra driver code for TwistedConnection, keeps on calling callLater, and I could not find a way to find if any of these calls are still pending, as these calls are hidden in the [`TwistedLoop`](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/blob/8d13b13437fe5c01984ddd0554be29425229b640/cassandra/io/twistedreactor.py#L152) class.

Questions:

- Is this correct way of handling cassandra query (which in turn would call twisted reactor)
- If yes, is there a way to address `DelayedCall` resulting from cassandra driver timeout (`reactor.callLater`).

Answer (score 0):

Just my understanding:

1. Maybe you will need to call `.filter` function while filtering? as mentioned in [docs](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/cqlengine/queryset.html) `setting = model.UserSettings.objects.filter(userid=userid).get()`
2. Maybe work around by change response time in Cassandra conf yaml file?